# Excel crashes, VBA userform cannot save

Tags: excel, vba, crash, autosave

I have a userform in Excel in which the user enters information and then hits an "add stock" button. Upon pressing this button, the information is entered into a spreadsheet and then the spreadsheet is saved with "ActiveWorkbook.Save".

The problem is that the work computers are old and Excel has a tendency to crash. When the spreadsheet is autorecovered, the add stock function no longer works, it crashes with a code 75 error. It seems that ActiveWorkbook.Save doesn't work in this case, until the user manually hits CTRL-S. The boss is adamant that our users are not computer savvy enough to manage this so I need to somehow check if Excel has crashed and if so automatically save the file before they start using it.

How would I check if we're in an autorecovery state, and then save it (without ActiveWorkbook.Save) so that the user can continue using the form without issues? Many thanks.

Comment: VBA error 75 is file/path access error, by crash do you mean the VBA halts? If so add error handling around the save method

Comment: No, Excel has a habit of crashing entirely, the whole application, forcing a restart and then autorecovery procedures.

Comment: And this is regardless of whether or not the userform is in use.

Comment: Would adding `Application.Sendkeys("^S")` work if you can check that `ActiveWorkbook.Save` doesn't save the file?

Comment: Boss wants it to check if we're in an auto recovery mode when the userform initializes, and then save the file. NOT upon use of the add stock function.

Comment: On opening the form check for the presence of the Autorecovered file in `Application.AutoRecover.Path`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a direct way to check this, but here are a couple of kludgy options.  It seems that if there are two states a workbook that an Autorecovered workbook can be in: Last saved by user or Autosaved. The caption reflects which state it's in.  This function will check for the existence of that phrase in the caption.

```
Public Function IsInAutoRecoverMode(wb As Workbook)

    Dim wn As Window

    Set wn = wb.Windows(1)

    IsInAutoRecoverMode = _
        wn.Caption Like "*[Autosaved]?" Or _
        wn.Caption Like "*[Last saved by user]?"

End Function
```

I'm not sure if there are more states that just this and this will certainly fail in non-English environments, so use with care.

When Last saved by user, the Workbook.Path property is where the file is stored.  When Autosaved, the Workbook.Path property is equal to Application.AutoRecover.Path. Well, they're equal on my machine. That may just be a coincidence, but I doubt it.

Because the Last saved by user Path isn't distinctive, you can't use it to determine if you're in Autorecover mode. But if the user open the Autosaved workbook, you probably don't want to just Save, but rather Save As in the right location. You might need to use both these techniques to get the solution you want.

Make sure you tell your boss that these work-arounds because you're so industrious and inventive, but they are not documented and might fail at any time.  At least, I wouldn't use them without understanding that they're based on some guesses. Let us know what you end up with.